# Dropdownlist objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, objectdatasource

I have a dropdownlist connected to a objectdatasource. How can I get the DataValueField=TypeId ? I use the onselectedindexchanged to get the selected Type, how can I do the same with TypeId?

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server"  
 DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" DataTextField="Type"  
 DataValueField="TypeId" AutoPostBack="true"  
 onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value:

```
int id = int.Parse(DropDownList.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand....do you want to get the selected value? In this case, this is what you have to do

```
string typeId = DropDownList.SelectedValue
```